# Octave hist plot number format

Tags: plot, formatting, scale, octave, histogram

I want to plot data with octaves `hist()` function. Unfortunately, as the numbers of the x-axis are quite large, they are displayed in scientific format, for example like 2e+007.

As this is a bit hard to read, I'd like them to be dislayed only as exponentials to the base 10, without the product or the e. So just like 10^5 for example. How can I achieve this?

When I plot data with the `loglog()` function, it uses the scale as I need it by default, but not for the `hist()`.

EDIT:

To be a bit more preceise, I add some code and a picture of my plot.

```
NUM_SAMPLES = 10000;
% Open file.
input = fopen(filename);

x = [];
for i=[1:NUM_SAMPLES]
    line = fgetl(input);
    data = strsplit(line, ';');
    x(end + 1) = str2num(data{1,2})/(1000);
endfor

% Close file.
fclose(input);

% Plot histogram.
figure('Position',[0,0,700,500]);
hist(x, 500);
```

So I just read some big numbers from my file and want to plot it with hist. Because the numbers are big, the automatically get displayed in loc scale and **scientific format**. Here you can see an example plot:

[image: Plot with bad number format on x-axis.]

Unfortunately `set(gca(), 'xscale', 'log');` doesn't change anything, so I think this plot is also consider log scale, but just a bad number format.

Comment: Can you post your code with some data to illustrate the question?

Comment: My input is just a vector with numbers and then I plot it with hist(duration, 500);. But as most numbers are really big, octave displays the numbers of the x-axis in the described format.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `xticklabel` or `yticklabel` manually, for example:

```
x = [1e7, 1e8, 1e9];
ax = gca();
set(ax, 'xticklabel', {'0','2e8','4e8','6e8','8e8','10e8'});
hist(x);
```

Alternatively, you can set the x axis to be in log scale:

```
set(ax, 'xscale', 'log');
```

Comment: I don't want to always set the labels manually. It should adapt to the data by itself, the same way it does it now. Only display the numbers in a different format. The last line is not working for me unfortunately.

Comment: @Chris, why the last line doesn't work? It sets log scale for the x axis. Please provide your data so that we can reproduce the desired `plot()` output and undesired `hist()` output.

Comment: I tried it on a smaller example now it worked. However it doesn't change for my original data. Probably because my problematic hist plot is also already in log scale, only a different way of writing the numbers. I'll add some more details to my question, but I really don't do any fancy stuff.

Comment: @Chris, please consider remove outliers in your data or use box plots instead. Histograms like the one you uploaded aren't helpful.

Comment: I'll zoom in to get the displayed the area I want in porper scale. Maybe a box plot could help as well, but I think its not as good to see how the values are distributed (frequency). Anyways, thats not an answer that helps solving my problem.

Comment: @Chris, my answer is still valid regardless of the data you plot. I don't know of any other solution for the moment. You can investigate all available customizations yourself by doing `ax = gca(); get(ax)`.